# Magento - Retrieve Layered Navigation Attribute ID

Tags: magento

I'm currently working with Magento CE 1.X, specifically in constructing a product view wrapping the simple products within their configurable product for a grouped display.

The issue I was having was that the layered navigation attributes were only applying to the Configurable product, not the simple products that are lumped within. I've set up a filter to accept the selected filter ID, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the ID itself.

The current loop i'm working with is this...

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
    foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
        $item->getName(); // Retrieves Name
        $item->getLabel(); // Retrieves selected value name
        $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar(); // Retrieves filter code I.E. color
    }
```

I haven't been able to sniff out the method for retrieving the option id which is used to filter the collection, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After snooping through the thousands of lines spit out by var_dumping $item, I found it can be accessed with...

```
$item->getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get option item's `attribute_code` or `attribute_id` with following code:

```
$item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode();
$item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeId();
```